# Is the state $0$ recurrent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}}$ be an irreducible Markov chain, i.e.  every state in the state space leads to every state in the state space.  Moreover, let the state space be the non-negative integers.

Is there a way to set up a of system of equations, or maybe a sequence of system of equations to determine whether or not the state $0$ is recurrent?

If so, how would such a thing look like?

Here we say that $x$ leads to $y$ iff $\rho_{xy}:=\Pr_{x}(T_{y}<\infty)>0$, where 
$T_{y}=\inf\{n, n>0\text{ such that } X_{n}=y\}$. We also say that $0$ is recurrent iff $\rho_{00}:=\Pr_{0}(T_{0}<\infty)=1$.

My attempt so far:

Since the chain is irreducible, either all states are recurrent or all states are transient, i.e. $\rho_{xy}=1$ or $\rho_{xy}<1$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ respectively...

Comment: You might consider, for some given state $x$, for every state $y$ and every real $s$ in $(0,1)$, $$u^x_s(y)=E_y(s^{T_x})$$ then the vector $(u^x_s(y))_y$ solves the affine system $$u^x_s(y)=sq(y,x)+s\sum_{z\ne x}q(y,z)u^x_s(z)$$ and the behaviour of the function $s\mapsto u^x_s(x)$ determines if the state $x$ is recurrent or transient since $$P_x(T_x\ \text{finite})=\lim_{s\to1}u^x_s(x)$$

Comment: This was what I was looking for.